# Looping through unnamed columns to plot on one graph in R

Tags: r, sapply

I have the following dataframe of unnamed columns.

```
test_df <- structure(list(V1 = c(738, 734.55, 731.05, 727.48, 723.86, 720.18, 
716.45, 712.66, 708.82, 704.91), V2 = c(383, 379.31, 375.69, 
372.13, 368.64, 365.22, 361.87, 358.6, 355.37, 352.19), V3 = c(704, 
700.8, 697.52, 694.15, 690.71, 687.19, 683.59, 679.92, 676.12, 
672.21), V4 = c(316, 312.77, 309.66, 306.66, 303.8, 301.07, 298.49, 
296.07, 293.79, 291.63), V5 = c(746, 743.64, 741.15, 738.52, 
735.78, 732.93, 729.98, 726.92, 723.69, 720.31), V6 = c(369, 
364.63, 360.37, 356.21, 352.15, 348.21, 344.39, 340.68, 337.04, 
333.48), V7 = c(715, 711.38, 707.74, 704.06, 700.36, 696.63, 
692.87, 689.09, 685.31, 681.51), V8 = c(349, 345.79, 342.62, 
339.49, 336.39, 333.33, 330.3, 327.31, 324.26, 321.2)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am looking to plot every 2 columns together on the same graph. The output of my data is such that the first column is the "x" variable and the column after is the "y" variable. 
For example column 1, column 2 is an x, y coordinate 
and column 3, column 4 is another x, y coordinate.

I am able to plot the first column, but then was having difficulties attempting to apply a function across the various unnamed columns.

```
plot(test_df$V1, test_df$V2, xlab="x", ylab ="y", xlim=c(200, 800), ylim=c(400, 200), main="vowel shapes", col= 'black', pch= ".")
lines(test_df$V1, test_df$V2, xlab="x", ylab ="y", xlim=c(200, 800), ylim=c(400, 200), main="vowel shapes", col= 'black', pch= ".")
lines(test_df$V3, test_df$V4, xlab="x", ylab ="y", xlim=c(200, 800), ylim=c(400, 200), main="vowel shapes", col= 'black', pch= ".")
```

I know that loops are not advised and so I felt funny looping through the length of the columns.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
matplot(test_df[seq(1,ncol(test_df), by=2)], test_df[seq(2,ncol(test_df), by=2)], t="l", lty=1)
```

Comment: Had the same thought but you beat me to it. I used `matplot(test_df[c(TRUE,FALSE)], test_df[c(FALSE,TRUE)], type="l", lty=1)`

Comment: This is amazing, and both so fast. In this particular case does matplot allow for changing of the limits of the graph? I was actually looking for y axis to go from 400 to 200, in other words in descending order from the origin. The plot basically needs to be reversed.

Comment: my mistake, found that it does. THANK YOU BOTH VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

With ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq(1,ncol(test_df), by=2), 
      function(x) data.frame(x=test_df[,x], y=test_df[,x+1], plot=as.factor((x+1)/2))))
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, group=plot, col=plot)) + geom_line(lwd=1.5)
```

[image]